# Dojo datepicker error

Tags: javascript, dojo, datepicker

I am experiencing a bug with Dojo's dijit.form.DateTextBox widget where if you select a valid date, and then enter an invalid date and then double click inside the entry box repeatedly, the widget stops responding and I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object. Uncaught Error: Tried
>   to register widget with id==datepickerDiv_popup_mdd but that id is
>   already registered

I created a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyoudy/YEnGb/1/

Follow these steps to reproduce the problem:

1. select a valid date from the date picker
2. click inside the date box and append something invalid to it, like a dash for example
3. double click repeatedly inside the textbox

I am using Dojo 1.6 and testing mostly with latest version of Chrome.

Any ideas how to overcome this error message?

Thanks

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the bug despite using chrome and clicking about 100 times in the textbox with invalid content...

Comment: Thanks @Philippe for trying this out. However, I am still able to reproduce this every single time. I removed all plugins but it still happens. I am running Chrome version 17.0.963.26 beta-m on Windows, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm using 16.0.912.75 on MacOSX lion... did you try to reproduce with a navigator other than chrome ?

Comment: Yes, I get a slightly different error message in Firefox but it seems to point to the same thing. Also triggered by clicking on and off the dropdown textbox... it is rather strange, happens somewhat randomly but can easily be produced on my end anyway. I was able to reproduce the issue on several browsers, different machines, etc so I know it isn't just my Chrome.